# Bluebird Map on HashMap/Obj

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I'm using the bluebird library to do asynchronous calls in javascript. I noticed there's a map function so I can apply a asynchronous function to each element in an array. However, I want to use this method on a object that has keys. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I realized after some research to just convert the obj into an array of objects where each element contains a property.

Comment: One-key objects are mostly always a bad idea. Does your mapping function need the key? What does it produce? Should your end result be an object again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many way to convert an object to array like this :

```
Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key){ return yourObject[key] })
```

You can use Promise.map too